# How to update a record using sequelize for node?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm creating a RESTful API with NodeJS, express, express-resource, and Sequelize that is used to manage datasets stored in a MySQL database.

I'm trying to figure out how to properly update a record using Sequelize.

I create a model:

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('Locale', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    locale: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
      validate: {
        len: 2
      }
    },
    visible: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      defaultValue: 1
    }
  })
}
```

Then, in my resource controller, I define an update action.

In here I want to be able to update the record where the id matches a `req.params` variable.

First I build a model and then I use the `updateAttributes` method to update the record.

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const { dbconfig } = require('../config.js')

// Initialize database connection
const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbconfig.database, dbconfig.username, dbconfig.password)

// Locale model
const Locales = sequelize.import(__dirname + './models/Locale')

// Create schema if necessary
Locales.sync()


/**
 * PUT /locale/:id
 */

exports.update = function (req, res) {
  if (req.body.name) {
    const loc = Locales.build()

    loc.updateAttributes({
      locale: req.body.name
    })
      .on('success', id => {
        res.json({
          success: true
        }, 200)
      })
      .on('failure', error => {
        throw new Error(error)
      })
  }
  else
    throw new Error('Data not provided')
}
```

Now, this does not actually produce an update query as I would expect.

Instead, an insert query is executed:

```
INSERT INTO `Locales`(`id`, `locale`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `visible`)
VALUES ('1', 'us', '2011-11-16 05:26:09', '2011-11-16 05:26:15', 1)
```

So my question is: What is the proper way to update a record using Sequelize ORM?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

I have not used [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com), but after reading its documentation, it's obvious that you are [instantiating a new object](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/instances.html), that's why Sequelize inserts a new record into the db.

First you need to search for that record, fetch it and only after that change its properties and [update](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-instances/#updating-an-instance) it, for example:

```
Project.find({ where: { title: 'aProject' } })
  .on('success', function (project) {
    // Check if record exists in db
    if (project) {
      project.update({
        title: 'a very different title now'
      })
      .success(function () {})
    }
  })
```

Comment: This works, however I did have to change `.success` to `.then`

Comment: Should it be `Project.findOne(` ?

Comment: Old question but relevant if searching today (as I did).  As of Sequelize 5, the correct way to find the record is with `findByPk(req.params.id)` which returns an instance.

Comment: This should not be recommended, it sends 2 queries where it could be done by single query. Please check other answers below.

Answer (score 316):

Since version 2.0.0 you need to wrap your **where** clause in a `where` property:

```
Project.update(
  { title: 'a very different title now' },
  { where: { _id: 1 } }
)
  .success(result =>
    handleResult(result)
  )
  .error(err =>
    handleError(err)
  )
```

---

### Update 2016-03-09

The latest version actually doesn't use `success` and `error` anymore but instead uses `then`-able promises.

So the upper code will look as follows:

```
Project.update(
  { title: 'a very different title now' },
  { where: { _id: 1 } }
)
  .then(result =>
    handleResult(result)
  )
  .catch(err =>
    handleError(err)
  )
```

#### Using async/await

```
try {
  const result = await Project.update(
    { title: 'a very different title now' },
    { where: { _id: 1 } }
  )
  handleResult(result)
} catch (err) {
  handleError(err)
}
```

See links: [docs Link](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/#updatevalues-options-promisearrayaffectedcount-affectedrows) and [API Link](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js%7Emodel#static-method-update)

Comment: Docs moved to: http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/model/#updatevalues-options-promisearrayaffectedcountaffectedrows

Comment: You have more upvotes than the first thread answer, i think it should be moved to the first answer of these answers thread. Cheers.

Answer (score 43):

Since sequelize v1.7.0 you can now call an update() method on the model. Much cleaner

For Example:

```
Project.update(

  // Set Attribute values 
        { title:'a very different title now' },

  // Where clause / criteria 
         { _id : 1 }     

 ).success(function() { 

     console.log("Project with id =1 updated successfully!");

 }).error(function(err) { 

     console.log("Project update failed !");
     //handle error here

 });
```

Comment: will this run validation too?

Comment: From what I've read in the API docs this is the preferred method.

Comment: It has actually been deprecated. See [the official API Reference for Model](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/wiki/API-Reference-Model#update).

Comment: [Here](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/model/#updatevalues-options-promisearrayaffectedcountaffectedrows) are the docs as of the time of this comment—they've moved to ReadTheDocs.

Comment: As mentioned, this notation is deprecated since 2.0.0. Please also refer to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26303473/831499

Answer (score 41):

**January 2020 Answer**
The thing to understand is that there's an update method for the Model and a separate update method for an Instance (record).  `Model.update()` updates ALL matching records and returns an array [see Sequelize documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#simple-update-queries). `Instance.update()` updates the record and returns an instance object.

So to update a single record per the question, the code would look something like this:

```
SequlizeModel.findOne({where: {id: 'some-id'}})
.then(record => {
  
  if (!record) {
    throw new Error('No record found')
  }

  console.log(`retrieved record ${JSON.stringify(record,null,2)}`) 

  let values = {
    registered : true,
    email: 'some@email.com',
    name: 'Joe Blogs'
  }
  
  record.update(values).then( updatedRecord => {
    console.log(`updated record ${JSON.stringify(updatedRecord,null,2)}`)
    // login into your DB and confirm update
  })

})
.catch((error) => {
  // do seomthing with the error
  throw new Error(error)
})
```

So, use `Model.findOne()` or `Model.findByPkId()` to get a handle a single Instance (record) and then use the `Instance.update()`

Comment: model.update(data, { where: {id: 1} }); is still working in 202 v6.x as per the answer from @kube

Comment: The problem, again, is that this would require two SQL transactions (select and update) instead of one (update).

Answer (score 32):

And for people looking for an answer in December 2018, this is the correct syntax using promises:

```
Project.update(
    // Values to update
    {
        title:  'a very different title now'
    },
    { // Clause
        where: 
        {
            id: 1
        }
    }
).then(count => {
    console.log('Rows updated ' + count);
});
```

Comment: This should be the top answer.

Comment: Not working in 2019: Unhandled rejection Error: Invalid value [Function]

Comment: Working fine with Sequelize 6.6.2 (June 2021).

Comment: Works well well with Sequelize 6.21.4 (Aug 2022)

Answer (score 18):

I think using `UPDATE ... WHERE` as explained [here](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/instances/index.html?highlight=update) and [here](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/model/#updatevalues-options-promisearrayaffectedcountaffectedrows) is a lean approach

```
Project.update(
      { title: 'a very different title no' } /* set attributes' value */, 
      { where: { _id : 1 }} /* where criteria */
).then(function(affectedRows) {
Project.findAll().then(function(Projects) {
     console.log(Projects) 
})
```

Comment: This sould be the accepted answer. This way you can only set some fields, and you can specify the criteria. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 15):

There are two ways you can update the record in sequelize.

First, if you have a unique identifier then you can use where clause or else if you want to update multiple records with the same identifier.

You can either create the whole object to update or a specific column

```
const objectToUpdate = {
title: 'Hello World',
description: 'Hello World'
}

models.Locale.update(objectToUpdate, { where: { id: 2}})
```

Only Update a specific column

```
models.Locale.update({ title: 'Hello World'}, { where: { id: 2}})
```

Second, you can use find a query to find it and use set and save function to update the DB.

```
const objectToUpdate = {
title: 'Hello World',
description: 'Hello World'
}

models.Locale.findAll({ where: { title: 'Hello World'}}).then((result) => {
   if(result){
   // Result is array because we have used findAll. We can use findOne as well if you want one row and update that.
        result[0].set(objectToUpdate);
        result[0].save(); // This is a promise
}
})
```

Always use transaction while updating or creating a new row. that way it will roll back any updates if there is any error or if you doing any multiple updates:

```
models.sequelize.transaction((tx) => {
    models.Locale.update(objectToUpdate, { transaction: tx, where: {id: 2}});
})
```

Answer (score 7):

This solution is deprecated

> failure|fail|error() is deprecated  and will be removed in 2.1, please
>   use promise-style instead.

so you have to use

```
Project.update(

    // Set Attribute values 
    {
        title: 'a very different title now'
    },

    // Where clause / criteria 
    {
        _id: 1
    }

).then(function() {

    console.log("Project with id =1 updated successfully!");

}).catch(function(e) {
    console.log("Project update failed !");
})
```

> And you can use `.complete()` as well

Regards

Answer (score 5):

You can use Model.update() method.

With async/await:

```
try{
  const result = await Project.update(
    { title: "Updated Title" }, //what going to be updated
    { where: { id: 1 }} // where clause
  )  
} catch (error) {
  // error handling
}
```

With .then().catch():

```
Project.update(
    { title: "Updated Title" }, //what going to be updated
    { where: { id: 1 }} // where clause
)
.then(result => {
  // code with result
})
.catch(error => {
  // error handling
})
```

Answer (score 4):

public static update(values: Object, options: Object):
Promise>

check documentation once http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-update

```
  Project.update(
    // Set Attribute values 
    { title:'a very different title now' },
  // Where clause / criteria 
     { _id : 1 }     
  ).then(function(result) { 

 //it returns an array as [affectedCount, affectedRows]

  })
```

Answer (score 4):

Using async and await in a modern javascript Es6

```
const title = "title goes here";
const id = 1;

    try{
    const result = await Project.update(
          { title },
          { where: { id } }
        )
    }.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

you can return result ...

Answer (score 4):

If you're here looking for a way to increment a specific field value in a model...

This worked for me as of `sequelize@5.21.3`

`User.increment("field", {by: 1, where: {id: 1});`

REF: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7268

Answer (score 2):

hi to update the record it very simple

1. sequelize find the record by ID (or by what you want)
2. then you pass the params with `result.feild = updatedField`
3. if the record doesn'texist in database sequelize create a new record with the params
4. watch the exemple for more understand
   Code #1 test that code for all version under V4

> ```
> const sequelizeModel = require("../models/sequelizeModel");
>     const id = req.params.id;
>             sequelizeModel.findAll(id)
>             .then((result)=>{
>                 result.name = updatedName;
>                 result.lastname = updatedLastname;
>                 result.price = updatedPrice;
>                 result.tele = updatedTele;
>                 return result.save()
>             })
>             .then((result)=>{
>                     console.log("the data was Updated");
>                 })
>             .catch((err)=>{
>                 console.log("Error : ",err)
>             });
> ```
>
> Code for V5
>
> ```
> const id = req.params.id;
>             const name = req.body.name;
>             const lastname = req.body.lastname;
>             const tele = req.body.tele;
>             const price = req.body.price;
>     StudentWork.update(
>         {
>             name        : name,
>             lastname    : lastname,
>             tele        : tele,
>             price       : price
>         },
>         {returning: true, where: {id: id} }
>       )
>             .then((result)=>{
>                 console.log("data was Updated");
>                 res.redirect('/');
>             })
>     .catch((err)=>{
>         console.log("Error : ",err)
>     });
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I used update method to update my record.

1. models is a .js file where your models place
2. users is model name
3. update is build in function provided by sequelize.
4. I'm updating name and city into users table where id equal to 1

```
models.users.update({req.body},
{where:{ id:1}}
)
```

Comment: I think it would throw an error, because the property "where" is outside of the brackets

Answer (score 0):

I have used `sequelize.js`, `node.js` and `transaction` in below code and added proper error handling if it doesn't find data it will throw error that no data found with that id

```
editLocale: async (req, res) => {

    sequelize.sequelize.transaction(async (t1) => {

        if (!req.body.id) {
            logger.warn(error.MANDATORY_FIELDS);
            return res.status(500).send(error.MANDATORY_FIELDS);
        }

        let id = req.body.id;

        let checkLocale= await sequelize.Locale.findOne({
            where: {
                id : req.body.id
            }
        });

        checkLocale = checkLocale.get();
        if (checkLocale ) {
            let Locale= await sequelize.Locale.update(req.body, {
                where: {
                    id: id
                }
            });

            let result = error.OK;
            result.data = Locale;

            logger.info(result);
            return res.status(200).send(result);
        }
        else {
            logger.warn(error.DATA_NOT_FOUND);
            return res.status(404).send(error.DATA_NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }).catch(function (err) {
        logger.error(err);
        return res.status(500).send(error.SERVER_ERROR);
    });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
Model.findOne({
    where: {
      condtions
    }
  }).then( j => {
    return j.update({
      field you want to update
    }).then( r => {
      return res.status(200).json({msg: 'succesfully updated'});
    }).catch(e => {
      return res.status(400).json({msg: 'error ' +e});
    })
  }).catch( e => {
    return res.status(400).json({msg: 'error ' +e});
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If `Model.update` statement does not work for you, you can try like this:

```
try{ 
    await sequelize.query('update posts set param=:param where conditionparam=:conditionparam', {replacements: {param: 'parameter', conditionparam:'condition'}, type: QueryTypes.UPDATE})
}
catch(err){
    console.log(err)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var whereStatement = {};

  whereStatement.id = req.userId;

  if (whereStatement) {
    User.findOne({
      where: whereStatement
    })
      .then(user => {

        if (user) {
          
          var updateuserdetails = {
            email: req.body.email,
            mobile: req.body.mobile,
            status: req.body.status,
            user_type_id: req.body.user_type_id
          };

          user.update(
            updateuserdetails
          )
            .then(function () {
              res.status(200).send({ message: 'Success...' });
            })
            .catch(err => {
              res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
            });
        }

        
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

### SEQUELIZE FIND AND UPDATE

> Using **async** and **await**

```
const approveUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {

  var userID = parseInt(req.params.id);

  const user = await User.findByPk(userID);

  if (!user) throw new Error('No record found');

  const result = await user.update({ isValid: !user.isValid });

  if (result) {
    res.status(201).json({
      result,
    });
  } else {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error('Invalid data');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Defined a `UserModel` so you can User

```
let data = await UserModel.update(body, {
  where: {
    id:id,
  },
  individualHooks: true,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update: 2023 (sequelize v6)**

The are 2 ways to update item.

1. Search the record and update.

```
const localeName = req.body.name;
const localeId = req.body.id;

const locale = await Locale.findOne({ where: { id: localeId } });
if (locale) {
    locale.name = localeName;
    await locale.save();
}
```

2. Update record with single query.

```
await Locale.update({ name: localeName }, {
  where: {
    id: localeId
  }
});
```

For the details docs.

https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/#simple-update-queries

**I find the 1st way is more useful.**

Comment: I'd avoid 1 way. There are: a) no reason to do 2 requests instead of 1; b) in some cases there could be a race