# Using sequelize, how do you use an OR operator with the where criteria?

Tags: mysql, node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

From a previous [SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471544/updating-multiple-records-using-sequelize-and-nodejs) I was able to update multiple sequelize instances with two conditions.

Can anyone explain how I can modify the sequelize .update method using a logical OR operator instead of an AND operator? Below is the sequelize .update method using AND for the two condition of updating.

```
  global.db.Task.update(
    {Desc: 'New Upate'},       //set attribute 
    {cd: 'match', Desc: null}  //where criteria 
  ).success(function(affectedRows) { ... });
```

This will read an SQL Statement as follows:

```
UPDATE "Task" SET "Desc"='New Update' WHERE "Cd"='match' AND "Desc" IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
global.db.Task.update(
    {Desc: 'New Upate'},       //set attribute 
    ["cd = ? OR Desc = ?", 'match', null]  //where criteria 
  ).success(function(affectedRows) { ... });
```

**Update** (from Miller): Added a comma that I missed in at the end of the set attribute line.

Comment: Are these changes you made considered raw SQL?

Answer (score 0):

global.db.Task.update({update_data}, {where: {where_data}}).then(function (affectedrows) {})

```
 global.db.Task.update({Desc: 'New Upate'},  where: {$or: [{cd: "match"}, {Desc: null}]}).success(function(affectedRows) { ... });
```