# Sequelize get promise

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

If I understand right I should be able to get the promise the way like that:

```
var helper = null;
MyModel.findAll().then(result => { helper = result });
```

In the examples this should be enough, but I do not get anything. If I assign a variable for the whole call I get promise pending.
The only "difference" I see from the examples is that I call it in an http request:

```
exports.somePostRequest = (req, res, next) => {
var helper = null;
myModel.findAll().then(result => { helper = result });
}
```

This works perfectly:

```
exports.anOtherrequest = (req, res, next) => {
  myModel.findAll()
  .then(result => {
    res.status(200).json({message: result})})
}
```

Some of the examples I was looking at:
https://sequelize.org/v3/docs/models-usage/
[How to update a record using sequelize for node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158244/how-to-update-a-record-using-sequelize-for-node)

Any suggestion why this does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var helper = null;
MyModel.findAll().then(result => { helper = result });
console.log(helper) // will be null
```

The problem with the approach above is that asynchronous operations like the one on line 2 will not happen in the order you expect it to. What happens in javascript is that line 1 executed, line 2 (asynchronous operation) is scheduled to run after all the synchronous operations gets executed, and line 3 runs, and finally all the asynchronous operations will complete (line 2 in this case).

So in simple words, the order of execution here is:

`line 1 completes >> line 2 is scheduled to complete later >> line 3 completes >> line 2 operation completes`

You can instead use `await` to make it go in order. Something like:

```js
var helper = null;
helper = await MyModel.findAll();
console.log(helper); // not null; yayy
```

This way everything runs in order. But keep in mind, await operations should be inside an `async` function. So you're server should look something like:

```js
exports.somePostRequest = async(req, res, next) => {
var helper = null;
helper = await myModel.findAll();
// or, var helper = await myModel.findAll();
// then do what you want with helper 
}
```

Alternative solution using `.then`

```
exports.somePostRequest = (req, res, next) => {
  myModel.findAll().then(result => 
    { 
       // work with the result here !
       // console.log(result);
    });
}
```

Comment: I thought  ".then" Meant to solve the async issue, or now? Also is not it bad to use async for http request?

Comment: On an other thought; if this is the only way to essentially make it async and to be sync with awaits, then well. I just though there is an other solution for this

Comment: `.then` does solve the async issue, but anything inside `.then` only runs once everything else has finished executing. So that means that any variable you assign inside `.then` will not be usable outside that scope.

Comment: In this case, if you need the helper variable to be used in the normal flow of execution, you will need to await for the result, or process the result inside the  `.then`, there's no other way around it.

Comment: thank you, yes makes sense, I just reviewed .then, async await and everything is clear now!